# How to implement clickable audio chapter links with Mediaelement Player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mediaelement.js

I use the Mediaelement Player to play audio. Right underneath the player I want to provide a list of chapters. If the user clicks on the chapter the player should jump to the correct time with `setCurrentTime()`.

This is how the audio element is embedded:

```
<audio src="file.mp3" preload="none"></audio>
```

The JavaScript to initialize the Mediaelement Player

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: '100%'
});
```

The html for the chapters looks like this:

```
<ul class="podcast-links-list">
    <li data-chapter-time="00:00:00.000"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">00:00:00</a> <span class="podcast-link-cite">Intro</span></li>
    <li data-chapter-time="00:02:26.375"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">00:02:26</a> <span class="podcast-link-cite">Wie funktioniert Minecraft?</span></li>
    <li data-chapter-time="00:05:29.310"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">00:05:29</a> <span class="podcast-link-cite">Crafting</span></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the exact time to jump is added as `data-chapter-time="00:05:29.310"` to the `<li>` element.

My JavaScript to react to clicks on the chapters is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    // call the functions if the user clicks on the li
    $('ul.podcast-links-list li').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            // fetch the player object
            var player = $('audio').mediaelementplayer({                
                success: function (me) {
                    alert($(this).data('chapter-time'));
                    // jump to the correct time, which is stored in data-chapter-time
                    player.setCurrentTime($(this).data('chapter-time'));
                    player.play();
                }
            });
        });
    });
 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

If I click on a chapter now I always get a JavaScript error:

```
TypeError: $('audio').mediaelementplayer is not a function. (In '$('audio').mediaelementplayer', '$('audio').mediaelementplayer' is undefined)
```

I really do not know why this happens. Can anyone help?

The MediaElement Player default controls work just fine by the way. I can play, pause etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this (this is a WordPress implementation) :

**In the HTML**,  change the format of the `data-chapter-time` content. Adopt the second's format instead of timecode format

*e.g.

`data-chapter-time="6.375"`* instead of `data-chapter-time="00:00:06.375"`

**js :**

```
settings.success = function (mejs) {
    $('ul.podcast-links-list li').on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     mejs.setCurrentTime($(this).data('chapter-time'));
     mejs.play();
    });
}

$('.wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-video-shortcode').mediaelementplayer( settings );
```